# Create unique name from array of names in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, nlp

I'm trying to create a unique name which includes all the data that could be found in an array of strings (names). It shouldn't repeat words.

Given this:

```
[
  'Xiaomi Mi',
  'Xiaomi',
  'Mi',
  'TV',
  'Stick',
  'Xiaomi Mi TV Stick',
  'Xiaomi Mi TV',
  'Mi TV Stick',
  'Mi TV',
  'TV Stick',
  'Reproductor',
  'Reproductor Multimedia',
  'Multimedia'
]
```

I would like to get something like this:

```
'Xiaomi Mi TV Stick, Reproductor Multimedia'
```

I would like to analyze the data (natural language processing, maybe) and come up with a unique name, so the solution shouldn't be about taking the longest elements in the array, for example.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest possible option would be

```
title = [...new Set(words.join(' ').split(' '))].join(' ')
```

which creates a long string from all array elements, splits that string into words, and concatenates unique words back.

If you want some "real" NLP, which would, for example, intelligently create  `"Xiaomi Mi Stick"` from `[Mi Stick Xiaomi]`, look around for a library. This is a complex problem that requires thousands lines of code.

Comment: I agree that something that actually identifies a weird order of words or is able to create a richer name would involve NLP libraries... Your solution might work for what I'm looking for though. Thanks!

Comment: Any idea what a solution involving a NLP library would be? at least point towards one that would work for this purpose.